# CSS styling procedure for vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I use `vue` using `cdn` link and using my component just like this.

```js
Vue.component('forward-button', {
  template: `
  <button type=button class="btn btn-default" @click="goURL">{{this.title}}</button>
 `,
  props: ['url', 'title'],
  methods: {
    goURL: function() {
      console.log(this.url);
      window.open(this.url);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <forward-button title="google" url="#"></forward-button>
</div>
```

How do I style this as the single file component? Don't want to use styling inside `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't use Single File Components when using vue through a cdn link.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#For-Users-New-to-Module-Build-Systems-in-JavaScript)

You can use a CSS file imported at the `<head>` of your HTML file like a regular website.

Comment: if I want to apply CSS only for this component what should I do? If I applied inside head then other elements can be affected

Comment: Use classes to style your elements, and make sure you separate the class names properly. BEM is a method for doing this, but others exist. https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/

If you define your css in classes like `forward-button__inner--default` for example instead of `btn-default`, you're OK.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: what you're asking is impossible without a build step. Using Vue through a CDN means it's pre-built for you. You can't use component scoped CSS, only global CSS to style components defined this way. So either, you use global CSS in a way that you make classes for each component separately, or you install and build vue locally.

Comment: I do understand. Thanks a lot for helping. Highly Appriciated